# Alterando dados de uma coluna inteira tabela - Python

Tags: python

batalha no laço "FOR"continua. bom, me deparei com um problema que nao consigo resolver. tenho uma tabela e todos seus dados são do tipo string, em uma certa coluna os dados de cada linha são letras e números, isso nao é um problema, eu fiz um laço "FOR", e limitei o tamanho da string assim:

```
i = []
for i in tabela['Valor']:
    i = i[3:7] # isso funcionou perfeitamente, mas nao consigo substituir os valores na coluna.
    #tabela['Valor'] = i # nessa tentativa nao funciona ficando apenas um numero em toda a coluna
    print(i)
```

tentei essa solução, mas "grava"apenas o ultimo dado do laço.

```
data = pd.DataFrame()
data['Valor'] = tabela['Valor']
i = []
for i in data['Valor']:
    i = i[0:8]
    print(i)
    tabela['Valor'] = i
    tabela = tabela.replace(tabela['Valor'])
```

quando mando printar a tabela, os valores da coluna 'Valor' fica sempre o mesmo o que está errado.

parte do dataset a ser alterado:

```
tabela['Valor']
output: 
tabela['Valor']
0                            R$ 0,02 por ação ITAUSA ON
1                 R$ 0,02120838006 por ação BANESTES ON
2                R$ 0,06270328053 por ação IHPARDINI ON
3                  R$ 0,816430716 por ação BRB BANCO ON
4                 R$ 0,02120838006 por ação BANESTES ON
5                            R$ 0,02 por ação ITAUSA ON
6             R$ 0,23690201678 por ação TELEF BRASIL ON
7                    R$ 6,4876594827 por ação COPASA ON
8                    R$ 0,02310 por ação CELUL IRANI ON
9     R$ 0,907735758004401 por ação SUL AMERICA UNT ...
10                  R$ 0,19477374027 por ação BRASIL ON
11                R$ 0,7158810908 por ação UNIPAR ON N1
12                  R$ 0,05652210279 por ação TAESA UNT
13                  R$ 1,19237597898 por ação TAESA UNT
14               R$ 0,19813998 por ação SLC AGRICOLA ON
15               R$ 0,34644526 por ação SAO MARTINHO ON
16                    R$ 0,2551403880 por ação TEGMA ON
17                    R$ 0,0850467960 por ação TEGMA ON
18             R$ 0,03264206955 por ação AES TIETE E ON
```

o objetivo final é reduzir o tamanho dessa string e aparecer apenas os 4 primeiros números.

Comment: Opa, vc pode colocar pelo menos um pedaço do dataset?

Comment: Olá Paulo, feito... veja se ficou mais claro agora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos aos passos usando somente o `pandas`

### Criar DataFrame

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["R$ 0,921222 qualquer coisa", "R$ 1,2345 outra coisa", "R$ 0,32212 ultima coisa"]})

>>> df

                            A
0  R$ 0,921222 qualquer coisa
1       R$ 1,2345 outra coisa
2     R$ 0,32212 ultima coisa
```

### Copiar de uma coluna para outra somente o que se quer

```
>>> df["B"] = df["A"].str[3:7]

>>> df
                            A     B
0  R$ 0,921222 qualquer coisa  0,92
1       R$ 1,2345 outra coisa  1,23
2     R$ 0,32212 ultima coisa  0,32
```

**Atualização do post 22/11/2020**

Conforme sugerido pelo [Flavio Moraes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/212699/flavio-moraes) nos comentários, uma possiblidade mais adequada seria a utilização de expressões regulares para achar os valores.

Segue abaixo a forma de se fazer isso

```
>>> df["C"] = df["A"].str.extract(r'(\d,\d+)')

>>> df
                            A     B         C
0  R$ 0,921222 qualquer coisa  0,92  0,921222
1       R$ 1,2345 outra coisa  1,23    1,2345
2     R$ 0,32212 ultima coisa  0,32   0,32212
```

Perceba, neste ponto, que as duas colunas são string e possuem a vírgula como delimitador para os decimais.

**Fim da atualização**

O pandas trabalha com ponto para a separação das casas decimais. Ainda temos vírgula.

### Converter vírugula para ponto

```
>>> df["B"] = df["B"].str.replace(",", ".")

>>> df
                            A     B
0  R$ 0,921222 qualquer coisa  0.92
1       R$ 1,2345 outra coisa  1.23
2     R$ 0,32212 ultima coisa  0.32
```

### Converter string para float

```
>>> df["B"] = df["B"].astype(float)

>>> df
                            A     B
0  R$ 0,921222 qualquer coisa  0.92
1       R$ 1,2345 outra coisa  1.23
2     R$ 0,32212 ultima coisa  0.32
```

Pronto. Agora é só trabalhar com os números da coluna B (neste exemplo)

**Continuação da atualização**

Neste ponto, caso vc tenha testado a substituição da vírgula por ponto e a conversão das duas colunas para float. Você teria:

```
>>> df
                            A     B         C
0  R$ 0,921222 qualquer coisa  0.92  0.921222
1       R$ 1,2345 outra coisa  1.23  1.234500
2     R$ 0,32212 ultima coisa  0.32  0.322120
```

Perceba que para a coluna `C` temos todas as casas decimais encontradas pela expressão regular. Caso queira que seja apresentada apenas duas, basta configurar o pandas para tal

```
>>> pd.options.display.float_format = "{:,.2f}".format

>>> df
                            A    B    C
0  R$ 0,921222 qualquer coisa 0.92 0.92
1       R$ 1,2345 outra coisa 1.23 1.23
2     R$ 0,32212 ultima coisa 0.32 0.32
```

**fim da continuação da atualização**

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Incrível! ficou perfeito....

Comment: Paulo, veja se pode ajudar-me novamente, nesse Data Frame tem 2 colunas com mesmo nome, como mudar ? é possível ?

Comment: Se vc achar pertinente, marque esta resposta como solução do seu problema. Respondendo: Se não forem muitas colunas, vc pode fazer `df.columns = ["A", "B", "C"...]`. De próxima vez, evite colocar uma nova pergunta nos comentários, abra uma outra pergunta.

Comment: Paulo dei um upvote na sua resposta porque além de funcional é bastante didática. Porém acredito que usar regex para obter a parcela da string referente ao valor é importante não apenas para lidar com problemas na formatação, mas também para casos em que os valores tenham mais ou menos do que 4 digitos. Outra opção menos segura seria usar split ou strip, que ainda sim seriam melhores do que a substring.

Comment: @FlavioMoraes, muito obrigado pela sugestão do `regex`. Atualizei o post incluindo isso.

Comment: @PauloMarques, excelente solução

Comment: Creio que neste caso em especifico o regex não é necessário(vai aumentar a complexidade e pode levar mais tempo), tendo em vista que os valores estão bem definidos e você não precisa buscar os valores no meio de textos mais complexos. Talvez um split bastaria. Mas muito boa a resposta. Grande abraço e um up vote pela resposta!